# How can I print a timestamp with RFC 2822 style time zone in Qt5?

Tags: c++, format, timestamp, qt5, qdatetime

I would like to format a `QString` to hold a description of a timestamp with offset from UTC specified on RFC 2822 format like this:

> +0800

for a positive offset of 8 hours, or

> -0100

for a negative offset of 1 hour.

I have studied the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1) for `QDateTime QDateTime::fromString(const QString & string, const QString & format)` but I can't really figure out which syntax must I use in the format string in the the call to accomplish this.

So how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have the full date, including the offset? QTimeZone might be useful in that case...

Comment: Good question. I would presume that QDateTime would take the current locale's offset when formating this as is common inf for example Java or PHP.

Comment: And I am a bit unsure how to use QTimeZone in this case. Could  you show me how?

Comment: By calling `timeZone()` on the QDateTime object, and then querying its `offsetFromUtc()`, which returns the number of seconds from UTC. You can then easily format that into a `+hhmm` format...